# Using Auth token between web pages

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

Working on a project with `django-rest-framework` as backend and creating a basic functional frontend which is communicating to the `rest-api(s)` services using ajax requests.

At login, used `Token Authentication` for users.
How am I supposed to obtained `token` after successful login to another template where it can be used for further calls to backend for authentication and fetching data purposes?

Please guide me to the best tutorial or any relevant doc. 
Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to save the token returned on login, and add the token to the authorization header for each request, or you can just use rest framework session authentication. This tutorial of django+angular is quite good in that sense. https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial/ You can also look at django rest auth https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth, this comes with registration/login api's.

Comment: @PieterHamman thanks for the docs!
yes im aware that I have to add the token for each request, the problem is where and how to save the token returned?

Comment: You can look at this as well http://www.codeotel.com/0NJgkgqqgq/token-based-authentication-in-django.html, its a bit outdated, they use custom middleware to do the token auth.